# Htaccess redirect from http to https and get params

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect this:

http://www.mysite.com/pages/addtocart.php?id=XXXX

to this

https://www.mysite.com/checkout/cart/addsku?id=XXXX

Up to now, this is what I have:

```
RewriteRule ^/pages/addtocart.php?(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/checkout/cart/addsku?$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it's not working. 
Help?

Answer (score 0):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^pages/addtocart\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/checkout/cart/addsku [L,R=302,NC]
```

**PS:** Query Parameter will automatically be carried over to new URL.